# Word for ‘steadily making things better’

Tags: single-word-requests

Are there any single English words that wholly capture the idea of incrementally making something better over time, or perhaps making steady improvements over time?

An example sentence:

> We strive to ____ (the world) through each small act.

Comment: Why do you think that 'has been improving' is not adequate for the purpose?

Comment: Please give us a sample sentence where the word belongs.

Comment: Growth and cultivation seem like good fits, I think.

Comment: I’m looking for a singe word for concisement. An example sentence: We strive to <word> (the world) through each small act.

Comment: I suggest that you make clear whether the sentence means 'We strive to (improve etc) _ourselves in the world_ through each small act'. Or 'we strive to (improve etc) the _environment of the world_ through each small act'. They are different concepts and have different vocabularies.

Comment: Improve usually has the connotation of small incremental steps rather than sudden change, although sometimes it can mean something more drastic.

Comment: The sample sentence here has been added by an editor; it may or may not reflect the OP's aims. Looking for a word other than *improve* seems even less necessary after the edit, as the rest of the sample sentence unambiguously conveys that the improvements are to be step-by-step.

Answer (score 2):

One candidate was hiding in your question:

> We strive to **better** the world through each small act.

**better** (transitive verb)

> To make more complete or perfect
>
> *looked forward to **bettering** her acquaintance with the new neighbors*
> [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/better)

---

> A real-world, project-based K-12 education that empowers kids to
> **Better Their World** was not feasible in the past—out kids were too powerless and isolated.
> [Marc Prensky; *Education to **Better Their World***](https://books.google.com/books?id=wtaqDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA29&dq=%22to%20better%22%20the%20planet&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjpioC9hISFAxXNN2IAHR6KDHAQ6AF6BAgKEAI#v=onepage&q=%22to%20better%22%20the%20planet&f=false) (2016)

> We have to figure out how we mitigate problems. We have to figure out
> how we adopt our current systems to **better the planet.**
> [Mark
> Minevich; Our Planet Powered by AI](https://books.google.com/books?id=Gs7cEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA23&dq=%22to%20better%20the%20planet%22%20in%20the%20generations%20to%20come&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0rPjDhYSFAxWRE1kFHZCcDLYQ6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=%22to%20better%20the%20planet%22%20in%20the%20generations%20to%20come&f=false) (2023)

> As we progress, it is crucial to continue in research, collaboration,
> and policy frameworks that promote AI technologies' responsible and
> ethical use **to better our planet and future generations**.
> [Anjali
> Yadov; "Leveraging Artificial Intelligence for Sustainable Development
> and Environmental Resilience" in Kannan et al. (eds); *Exploring
> Ethical Dimensions of Environmental Sustainability and Use of AI*](https://books.google.com/books?id=EU_pEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA163&dq=%22to%20better%20our%20planet%22%20in%20the%20generations&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQ-suLnYaFAxXUEVkFHdY5An4Q6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22to%20better%20our%20planet%22%20in%20the%20generations&f=false) 
> (2023)

Answer (score 0):

Ameliorating—-though this is not necessarily over time.

> to make better or more tolerable *medicine to ameliorate the pain* ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ameliorate))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I associate this word with the improvement of something that is bad. While a more general sense of improvement is supported by dictionaries, in my experience the general usage is very unusual.

Comment: *Ameliorate* is neither better nor worse for the OP's purposes than *improve*; it is just a fancy synonym for it.

Comment: I've added an M-W reference to this answer, as it turned up in my review queue. User500463, do give some time to the [tour] when you can. Answers are expected to show a dictionary or other reputable publication supporting your answer if possible. It is up to you to show how _ameliorate_ is a good answer for the original question. Welcome to ELU!

Answer (score -2):

**tl;dr**
Thrive, improve, accelerate, elevate, increase, expand, rise, grow, excel, advance.  I also like [excelsior](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/excelsior#dictionary-entry-2), but while it may have a special place for New Yorker's, it is also Latin and not in broad conventional use.

**Details:**
**[Thrive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thrive)**: The word "thrive" has a broad scope, and is applicable to various domains. It implies not just organic growth, but **flourish**-ing, and successful development, making it a suitable choice for describing steady improvements over time in a wide range of contexts, such as personal growth, business development, or environmental progress. The term may resonate with people who seek personal and professional growth.

**[Grow](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grow)**: "Grow" is a versatile term that can be applied in various domains, such as horticulture personal growth, business development, or environmental progress. It can imply steady growth but is less specific than "thrive" and may be more appropriate in describing the end result rather than the process of incremental improvement. The term may resonate with people who are focused on personal and professional growth.  Similar to nurture, cultivate.

**[Improve](https://improve)**: "Improve" is a generic term that can be applied to almost any domain, but it may lack specificity and may not fully capture the idea of steady progress over time. The term may resonate with people who strive for self-improvement and societal progress.  Similar to Develop, advance, augment, and magnify.

**[Accelerate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accelerate)**: The word "accelerate" is most suitable in contexts where speed or efficiency is the primary focus, such as a factory, where it can imply increasing production or reducing cycle times. It may not be the best fit for describing steady improvements over time in a broader sense, as it suggests a sudden change rather than a gradual, incremental one. The term may resonate with younger individuals, both male and female, and those with higher income levels who are ambitious and seek rapid advancement. Also racing or sports fans.  Similar to boost, upgrade, refine.

**[Elevate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elevate)**: "Elevate" is most appropriate in contexts where the focus is on raising or lifting something to a higher level, such as an airplane or an barge building. It can also be used metaphorically to describe an increase in status or quality. However, it doesn't capture the idea of incremental growth or steady progress.  An elevator trip is an event not a process, and not everybody gets to the top floor.  The term may resonate with people with higher income levels who aspire to elevate their social standing.  Similar to Ascend, Escalate.

**[Rise](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rise)**: "Rise" is most appropriate in contexts where the focus is on an upward movement, such as a stock price or a person's career. It is very similar to elevate.  The new term "[Riz](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/riz)" might appeal as a synonym to younger audiences. The term may resonate with people who aspire to rise in their personal and professional lives. Similar to Elevate.

**[Increase](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/increase)**: "Increase" is a versatile term that can be applied in various domains, such as business, finance, or personal growth. In modern use, it implies a quantitative change rather than older implication of steady improvement or growth over time. The term may resonate with people who are focused on increasing their wealth and resources. Similar to improve, refine, advance, progress, and amplify.

**[Expand](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expand)**: "Expand" is most suitable in contexts where the focus is on broadening or extending something, such as a business expanding its market or a person expanding their skill set. It is a colonial word.  It can imply growth, but not necessarily in a steady or consistent manner, making it less suitable for describing steady improvements over time. The term may resonate with people  who seek to expand their horizons and influence. Similar to enhance.

**[Excel](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/excel)**: "Excel" is most suitable in contexts where the focus is on outperforming others or achieving exceptional results, such as in academics or sports. It can imply progress but not necessarily in a consistent or incremental manner, making it less suitable for describing steady improvements over time. It is also the name of a Microsoft Office software tool. The term may resonate with people who strive for excellence and recognition.  Mileage may vary for analytical types.

Comment: Updated with more detail.  Thanks.